# Print message AFTER shutdown completes?

Tags: shell-script, embedded, shutdown, petalinux, halt

I am using a bash script with the shutdown command to halt my system. I know that shutdown can print a message as an argument. Here's my current command:

```
shutdown -h now "Shutdown complete. You may now unplug the power."
```

However, this prints my message *before* the shutdown command does its thing, and so I see a ton of other messages afterwards, such as "INIT: Sending processes the TERM signal" and "Unmounting local filesystems..."

I want to print a final message at the end of the halt, so that the user knows when it is safe to unplug the power. How can I do this?

(I am on an embedded system running Petalinux 2019.1.)

Comment: If the system is halted, how can the computer possibly communicate to the user?

Comment: I don't need the message to be printed after everything halts, just after all the other shutdown steps are completed.
Instead of command->message->prep->halt, I want command->prep->message->halt

Comment: Where do you expect to see the message?

Answer (score 1):

This is a semi-educated guess:

This would be saved to `/etc/rc0.d/K01zzz_goodbye_message`

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
echo "Shutdown will complete soon. Unplug me."
```

Comment: I do see a S90halt script there, I could edit it, or make the new one as you suggest. I'll try these out tomorrow and see what works

Comment: The `S` scripts and the `K` scripts run at different times ("start" and "kill" if I recall, I only play a sysadmin online), so do some research.

Comment: Yeah they're run in alphabetical order. Putting that goodbye_message script just before halt (S89) still had it before a lot of the other shutdown messages. I think the correct course is to add the echo at the end of the halt script itself